# What can we say about eigen values of adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, dual-spaces

$T: V \to V$ be a linear operator. Adjoint of T is defined as $T^{×}: V' \to V'$ and $T^{×}g = gT$.
If $\lambda$ is an eigen value of T such that $T(x)= \lambda x$ for some non zero vector $x\in V$. Then we have  $T^{×}g(x)= \lambda g(x)$ . But this doesn't imply $T^{×}g = \lambda g$. Another property of this adjoint operator is that the matrix representation of $T^{×}$ is equal to the transpose of that of $T$. So from this can we say eigen values of $T$ and $T^{×}$ are same.

Comment: There are no mention of norms in this question; is $V'$ the algebraic dual of all functionals, or the continuous dual of all bounded functionals (with $V$ having some kind of norm)?

Comment: $V'$ is the space of all continuous linear functionals on $V$